# MVVM VS WPF Browser Application?

Tags: wpf

How to use MVVM in WPF Browser Application?

I want to know how to use MVVM in WPF Browser application,

Is that really worthful when comapre with **Silverlight**?

Which technology is having higher performance for **mvvm** Silverlight or WPF?

I am going to have my Business layer using **ASMX 2.0 (or) WCF**

Please help me on this,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is by looking at the [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) framework.  It will allow you to implement the MVVM pattern in a WPF browser application.  I have been using this technique for sometime without any issue.